# Debian wheezy - lost gnome during install

Tags: linux, debian, gnome

Upgraded dist, no problem, although lost xbmc, found documentation saying to include additional source for xbmc as install wasn't working.

installed xbmc not realising it's completely replaced/up/down graded dist.

Needless to say I've lost gnome and samba config has been modified. i can fix after i get desktop back, packages are still there but no longer referenced.

when i try an `apt-get install gnome` i get a lot of message about Dependants and how they're not going to be installed.

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo aptitude install gnome-desktop-environment`, review solution and do not accept it until you're happy with what's going to be installed/removed.